# IE9 renders completely different to any other browser - bootstrap based site

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have no idea why IE9 is giving such a different rendering to any other browser, IE10 works great as well as all other modern browsers.

My site is based on bootstrap 3.

I'm not sure where to start looking as the dev tools within IE9 are terrible.

Anyone have any ideas on where to start or what it could be:

http://www.house-mixes.com

Paul

Comment: A common reason for IE misbehaviour is the compatibility mode.  Check if it's opening the site in compatibility view.

Comment: no compatibility view is off, if turned on my site acts as if it's in responsive mode for a mobile device, menus are collapsed etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your DOCTYPE to

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

and add this meta element

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Comment: Press F12 and look for 'browser mode' and 'document mode'. What are they set to?

Comment: Browser Mode: IE9, Document Mode: IE9 Standards

Comment: i should point out it's not the home page, http://www.house-mixes.com/mixes is an example which doesn't render correctly.

Comment: `GET http://www.house-mixes.com/assets/less/css/bootstrap.css 404 (Not Found) `

Your bootstrap.css is not loading. This may be causing your website to look the way it does. The only reason it works in IE10 is, possibly, that your bootstrap.css was cached and therefore loading regardless.

Comment: ignore that, that was me testing just. bootstrap is embedded in the other css file.

Comment: Well I notice you have several `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements. This is pretty prevalent in most sites that use bootstrap, however I have read that these can cause issues with older versions of IE. I suggest removing them and seeing if that fixes it.